# "Lift the suspension" vs "Drop the suspension"

Tags: meaning, phrases

My sense is that these phrases mean the same thing: the suspension has been reversed or nullfied.

Here's the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lifted+the+suspension%2Cdropped+the+suspension&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), for what it's worth.

The fact that "lifted the suspension" is much more popular than "dropped the suspension" surprises me, since I'm inclined to think that the way to counteract a suspension should be to put it down, not further up.

So two questions.

(1) Is the Ngram right that we should prefer *lift* to *drop* in this context?

(2) Regardless of what is "right," how did the seemingly counter-intuitive phrase come to be the dominant one?

Comment: Besides lifting and dropping, one can do any number of other things to a suspension— raise it, cancel it, perhaps even suspend it. In a different sense, your car's suspension can also be lifted or dropped (perhaps while waiting for your school suspension to be lifted or dropped). So even if an n-gram could tell us right from not right, this is not an adequate nGram to use.

Comment: Let's not forget that "suspension" is also a kind of bridge.

Comment: @choster: I think the NGram is quite adequate for showing that *lift* occurs far more often than *drop* with *suspension*. The fact that there are multiple senses for the word suspension that can actually *be* "dropped/lifted" isn't really any more relevant than the fact that one very common one (small solid particles in a suspending liquid) can't apply with any such words in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lift has other meanings in addition to "raise up"

[It can also mean](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lift#Etymology_2): to rescind or revoke as in an embargo or a suspension.

Answer (score 0):

Drop has the idea of dropping the issue, giving up, etc., whereas lift still implies being in control. At least it seems that way to me.